# centering text positioning using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to do a simple website recreation using flexbox. Here is the final goal (for this step):[image]

Pretty simple. But I am struggling with aligning the text. I am able to get the header to center just fine. It's mainly the paragraph underneath that I am having trouble centering. Is there a way to center that paragraph vertically and horizontally to its outer container? New to flexbox and would like any tips! Here is a link to my codepen and relevant code: https://codepen.io/gkunthara/pen/qjympg

HTML

```
 <div class = "content-container">
<h1 class = "main-header"> Connect with Subscribers Effortlessly </h1>
 <p class = "sub-header"> Email Marketing Platform for Bloggers & 
Authors. </p>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .content-container  .main-header{

  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 45px;
  height:75px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-style: solid;

}

.content-container .sub-header {
  border-style: solid;
  display: flex;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do two things.

**1.** Add

```
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
```

to your `.content-container` class.

**2.** Remove `margin-top: 150px` from `.content-container .sub-header` and it should be it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 15px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.content-container .main-header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 75px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-style: solid;
}

.content-container .sub-header {
  border-style: solid;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <h1 class="main-header"> Connect with Subscribers Effortlessly </h1>
  <p class="sub-header"> Email Marketing Platform for Bloggers & Authors. </p>
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle to play with.](https://jsfiddle.net/bmpL48yr/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `margin-top` in your `.content-container .sub-header` rule and add `flex-direction: column; align-items: center;` to your `.content-container` the text will center properly

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRjReY)

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 75px;
}

.header-container .logo {
  width: 250px;
}

.header-container .logo .sb {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.header-container .nav-bar-container {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4B4B4B;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.content-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.content-container .main-header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 45px;
  height: 75px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-style: solid;
}

.content-container .sub-header {
  border-style: solid;
  display: flex;
  height: 25px;
}


/* Resize window to see its effect */

@media( max-width: 700px) {
  .header-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <a class="logo"> <img class="sb" src="logo.png" alt="logo"> </a>
  <nav class="nav-bar-container">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Tour </a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Pricing </a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Medium </a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Sign Up </a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Login </a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
  <h1 class="main-header"> Connect with Subscribers Effortlessly </h1>
  <p class="sub-header"> Email Marketing Platform for Bloggers & Authors. </p>
</div>
```

---

If you intended to center the `.content-container .sub-header` w/o take the `.content-container  .main-header` into account, you need to position the `.content-container  .main-header` absolute

With this, it will work with or w/o the `flex-direction: column;`, which I added in the first solution.

*Note though, that on less wider screen you need to adjust both, or else they will overlap*

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRjRvX)

Added these properties to your `.content-container  .main-header`

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
```